# Assign vectors from MATLAB workspace (struct) to Simulink Model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need help with running a Simulink model with the data from MATLAB workspace contained in structures. Below is a very simplified use-case of what I would like to do

Use Case :

I have a structure in MATLAB workspace called "data_in", and it has two fields x, and y which are vectors. I have a simulink model with two `Inports` named x and y.

This is what I would like to to :

a. Read the name of the Inports from the Simlunk Model. In this case it would be x and y

b. Programmatically assign the data from the structure - "data_in" to the ports "x" and "y" in the Simulink model. The structure "data_in" contains two vectors "x" and "y" to be mapped to Simulink Inports

The above use case is a very simplified scenario. The model that I intend to use can have 100 inports, and thus I do not want to use "From Workspace" block, as it would be impractical for me to add 100s of them

How can I handle such a situation in Simulink. I am a little more than a beginner in MATLAB and Simulink. So, a detailed answer would help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get correctly your question, and the inputs are time-variables, you may use `From Workspace` and call your initialization script by `InitFcn` in `Callbacks`.

assuming you have an initialization script named `init_script`:

put in `InitFcn` this: `init_script`; so as you run Simulink that script is run first.

assume this is your timeseries in `init_script`:

```
ts = timeseries(randn(10,2),'Name','TS');
```

put ts in the `From Workspace`:
[image]

But if these are not time variant vectors do the same and use `constant` block instead, inside its value field put the vectors' name and again put the script that contains these vectors in `InitFcn` in `Callbacks`:

```
X = randi(10,6,1); 
Y = randi(10,6,1);
```

then do the operations you need:
[image]

so the To Workspace block named as simout will give you:

```
simout.Data(:,:,1)
ans =

14
 9
16
16
10
 3
```

and finally, if you have lots of those vectors and components, you can create them easily from Matlab Workspace:

```
my_struct.x = randn(6,1);my_struct.y = randn(6,1);
new_system('myModel')
open_system('myModel')
pos = [10   10   20   30]
for i =1:10
    add_block('built-in/Inport',['myModel' '/In1'],'Position',pos);
    add_block('built-in/Constant',['myModel' strcat('/Cx', num2str(i))],'Position',pos+2);
    add_block('built-in/Constant',['myModel' strcat('/Cy', num2str(i))],'Position',pos+i);
    pos = pos + 1;
    X_vector = my_st.x
    set_param(strcat('myModel/Cx', num2str(i)),'Value', X_vector)
    Y_vector = my_st.x
    set_param(strcat('myModel/Cy', num2str(i)),'Value', Y_vector)
....
```

of course this for loop code is here to give you the idea, and in reality will be more complex and you will know how to handle it the best.